# Anything special about the internal structure of Carbon-12?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

In trying to understand the various structures carbon forms, I'm wondering what, if anything, is so special about having 6 neutrons and 6 protons in the nucleus. I'm aware there are permutations possible (in general) with respect to the specific arrangement of nucleons.

On the surface of the issue it seems like there is something about the internal structures possible that is peculiar... It isn't a rational train of thought but it is tempting to ask if there is something more to the internal structure - a lot of 3's and 2's appearing suggesting a geometric or numeric answer...

I've tried to think of it as a sphere packing problem, knowing that the analogy wouldn't be entirely appropriate, haven't gotten far yet. Also wondering if there is any relation to icosahedra, having 12 vertices and a plethora of interesting geometrical properties.

In short, is there anything to be said about the internal structure of Carbon-12 that's remarkable or distinct to that isotope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon-12 is an "alpha-cluster nucleus," with even proton number $Z$, even neutron number $N$, and $N=Z$. The alpha-cluster nuclei up to argon or so are slightly more stable than than their "mirror nuclei" neighbors at $Z-2,N+2$, and tend to be concentrated in stellar nucleosynthesis.

Nuclear structure is a big subject where lots of different approaches are good at explaining various phenomena.

- The [cluster model](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Clusters_in_nuclei) is one approach (or at least, a phenomenon that should arise from a good microscopic nuclear model).
- The [shell model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model) follows the same sort of four-quantum-number ruleset that leads to the electron structure of the periodic table. For subtle reasons the nucleon shells fill differently that electron shells do: the noble gases have $2,10,18,36,\cdots$ electrons, while the "magic nuclei" have $8,20,28,50,\cdots$ protons and/or neutrons.
- For heavy nuclei you can kind of gloss over the details of what's happening inside and model the nucleus as a [liquid drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula).

Each of these approaches has strengths and weaknesses.
I'm not aware of an approach that involves icosahedra.

Note that whether your model includes nucleons or clusters, the nucleus is profoundly quantum-mechanical.
The wavelength of *each nucleon* is comparable to the size of the nucleus, and the overlap and interference between them is a fundamental part of the nuclear dynamics.
This is very much unlike atoms packed into a crystal lattice in a solid; it's more like the ocean of nonlocalized conduction electrons in a metal.

Comment: From a quick look it seems like the cluster model would explain this best, even if not entirely. It isn't exactly a "physical" interpretation but it does look like nature enjoys sphere packing - 4 nucleons into an alpha particle, and 4 alpha particles for O-16, etc... Though I'm still unsure if the triangular structure itself gives rise to any of Carbon-12's properties or if it just explains its stability.

Comment: See my edit. The first magic number is 8, in a hand-waving way, because two nucleons fit into the $s$ orbital and six into the $p$ orbitals. "Packing" isn't something you can really do in quantum mechanics.